# Drawing above **everything** on the screen

Tags: c#, graphics

There are numerious posts that cover this topic. However, none seem to provide the answer I am looking for.

The application F.lux places an orange/red-ish colour overlay on the screen.

I am attempting to do something similar. The problem is, all solutions I have come across do not draw above the taskbar.

F.lux does so, so, surely it is possible.

How can I go about drawing an overlay above **everything** on the screen with C#?

**Edit**
... Or altering each pixel that is sent out to the GPU.

Comment: F.lux just changes the colour balance settings of the OS. It doesn't need to draw anything.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the color of everything on the screen is not typically done using an overlay. It is done by altering the color scheme at a fundamental level, e.g. changing the system color scheme or all application elements (background, menu, toolbars, fonts, etc.).

For example, see http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/change-colors-on-your-computer